# Text overflowing out of @media print

Tags: html, css, printing, media-queries

I have a parent container, with several child containers. Here is the styling of each:

```
@media print {
  #par-container {
     width: 100% !important;
     position: absolute !important;
     top: -10px !important;
     left: -25px !important;
     margin-left: 5px !important;
     margin-right: 5px !important;
  }
}
```

--

```
 .child-container {
   margin-top: 50px;
   width: 100%;
   border: solid;
   border-color: grey;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   display: block;
}
```

--

```
<div id="par-container">
  <div className="child-container">stuff1</div>
  <div className="child-container">stuff2</div>
  <div className="child-container">stuff3</div>
  <div className="child-container">stuff4</div>
</div>
```

When I try to print the document, the text inside of the child container overflows the **height** of the child container, by overflowing the bottom of the container.

Because I used `width: 100% !important` in `par-container`, there is no overflow beyond the width. That is fine.

I wish I could show a screenshot of it, but I cannot due to privacy.

Answer (score 0):

your page will be owerflow from top of page in print because of your top -10px code in #par-container
if you remove this code its will be fix and i recommend give a
width 90 or 95% when its have to print because the printed pages are smaller

```
.child-container {
>           margin-top: 50px;
>           width: 100%;
>           border:5px solid gray;
>           border-radius: 5px;
>     }
>     
>     @media print {
>           #par-container {
>              width: 100%;
>              position: absolute;
>              top: -10px;
>              /* left: -25px; */
>              margin-left: 5px;
>              margin-right: 5px;
>           }
>           .child-container {
>                 width: 90%;  
>           }
>     }
```

[like this ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3CKv.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I can provide from what I understood from your question.

```css
@media print {
  #par-container {
     width: 100% ;
     position: absolute ;
     padding: 0 20px;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.child-container {
   margin-top: 50px;
   width: 100%;
   border: 2px solid grey;
   border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="par-container">
    <div class="child-container">stuff1</div>
    <div class="child-container">stuff2</div>
    <div class="child-container">stuff3</div>
    <div class="child-container">stuff4</div>
  </div>
```